# Django comments framework

Tags: django, django-contrib

Hi I am quite new to Django and am trying to get to grips with a few things.

I would like to know if the comments framework that is bundled with django can redirect to the refering page if the comment form contains errors?

Also if I were to make a rating framework how would I go about achieving this functionality. Would I simply pass the refering url inside my rating form?

Thanks for any help

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who dealt with the first issue, I can say I could not find a way, at least without having to modify the app. I took the other path and wrote an app that suited me better. I posted a question on SO related to this issue, you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093877/django-returning-form-errors-from-a-generic-application-view).

Regarding your second question, there is a rating app for Django, you may check it [here](http://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings/tree/master).

Comment: I know this a very old post, but I am having the same problem you once had. You have written that you created your own app. Can you please share that if thats ok with you?